# Where can I see a comprehensive log of google play services c++ SDK?

Tags: android, c++, google-play, google-play-services

I'm integrating google play services SDK in unreal engine (saved games). The engine already uses a version of the c++ SDK (1.1). Now I see the latest version is 1.3 and thinking if its worth the change. But I can not see anywhere a changelog / revision log / news whatever.

What are the improvements / bug fixes / news  of 1.3 vs 1.1 ?

Thanks